# Open popup on leaflet from outside of map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am using leaflet maps, when I click on the map the map will open a popup in a set place and center on the location using the following code.

```
  var popup = L.popup();

 function onMapClick(e) {
popup
    .setLatLng([40.737, -73.923])
    .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
    .openOn(thisLeafletMap);
     thisLeafletMap.panTo(new L.LatLng(40.737, -73.923));
}

 thisLeafletMap.on('click', onMapClick);
```

However I want the above code to work when a set html element is clicked rather than the map.

So I was trying something like

```
  $('.lid').click(function() {
 // 
  });
```

Where .lid is the element to be clicked, but I do not know how to declare the function properly, what would I need to put in the above click function to open the popup as declared in the popup above?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to merge them I just put

```
   $('.lid').on('click', onMapClick);
```

So the query ran when I clicked th div instead of the map

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#popupid').click();
```

and then make sure you have

```
  data-rel="popup"  in your anchor tag....I just looked at some older code of mine that works, It if that does not do the trick Let me know. I will go find what is missing
```